# How to output the string (in the console) between quotation marks?

Tags: java, string

I have a text file and the contents are:

```
"hello world"
```

My goal is to output only:

```
hello world
```

My question is HOW TO DO IT? Thank you in advance programmers!

Comment: By programming it.

Comment: Using `replaceAll`.

Comment: `string.replace("\"", "");`

Comment: That is still an unclear requirement. Can the string contain other double quotes and if yes what should be done with them. Same idea can blank characters be in the file before or after the string, and again what should be done.

Comment: And anyway you are supposed to show a honest attempt. How could this be upvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
  {
  File file = new File("input.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String st;
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(st.replace("\"", ""));
  }
}
```

> input.txt
>
> "hello world"

Output:

```
hello world
```

Comment: Thank you Jay! Appreciate it.